# What asp.net-mvc strongly typed helpers uses underneath?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strong-typing

For example, if i use this in view:

```
${Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.UserName)}
```

How can i

```
var name = [xxx].NameFor<User>(u=>u.UserName);
```

from elsewhere? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression expression)`